# Showing JFree chart image from local machine in a web application

Tags: java, html, image, struts2, jfreechart

I am generating a chart using JFree charting library. After generating it, I am saving it to the local machine(The requirement document specifically reads that I have save it in local machine).

Now there is an a drop down in the Web UI, to export the generated image to excel or to render the image in Web page itself.

Since I am saving the image in the local machine, **the  *img src* html tag, does not work.**

Is there any way to get around the problem ?

Server used : Weblogic

Answer (score 2):

You need to programatically read the contents of the file from the disk and serve it through some servlet using stream , and set the url of the Img tag in page to this servlet .

Comment: @trashgod He is trying to serve a local image on server to the HTTP clients , this image was created dynamically from the code using jcharts api, generally we directly save the image to stream for the request , might be for some business needs , he needs to save them first to the disk and then serve them via servlet

Comment: I think I understand; it's what we used to do before the stream methods in `ChartUtilities` matured. I'm urging him to verify the requirement. Without a policy, disk storage will increase without bound.

Comment: @trashgod Are/were you a member of JFreeCHarts ?

Comment: Yep, a satisfied customer for most of this millennium. :-)